# Getting windows gmail notifications on my app

Tags: c#, .net-core, windows-10, gmail-api

I am building an app that uses the Gmail API that will run as a windows service, get Gmail notifications when a new email has arrived, do some functionality with that email and then mark it as READ.

my question is is there any way of getting those Gmail notifications inside my app? just like I get them on my desktop (windows 10).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to some sort of create `Push Notifications` service and the [official gmail api](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push) has guidelines and [quick start](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/quickstart-console) to allow you doing that.